# PHP GET not changing?

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

I built a switch to change the order of ascending and descending a sort, the $_GET['sense'] is the way it should be sorted, when it is ASC, the next time $sorting should be DESC ( I pass this to a function to add this to a url). However it never changes from DESC to ASC. I can't figure out why.

The important statement is the if($sorting) :

I want to say if the variable is ASC it should be DESC, if it is anything else (DESC hopefully) then it should be ASC again. But this doesn't seem to work.

```
 if(isset($_GET['column']) && isset($_GET['sense'])){
            $sorting = antiInjectie($_GET['sense']);

            $temp = antiInjectie($_GET['column']);

            if($sorting = "ASC"){
                $sorting = "DESC";
            }else{
                $sorting = "ASC";
            }

            if(tableNameMatcher($temp)){
                $order = $temp;
            }

        }else{
            $order = "naam,voornaam";
            $sorting = "ASC";


        }
```

**note** The second else statement is for when there isn't anything given

Answer (score 4):

use `if($sorting == "ASC"){` instead of `if($sorting = "ASC"){` as your if-clause (you forgot a `=`)

explanation: in your if-clause you always set `$sorting` with 'ASC' (you do no comparision)

Comment: Don't, this is a mistake everyone HAS to make. If you want to avoid this, do your if conditions like this: `if('value' == $var)`. Thus, if you forgot a `=`, it will throw an error and you will see where the problem is. Some people call this style 'Yoda Conditions`. (Use the force you must)

Answer (score 1):

You can streamline this code a bit and solve your issue at the same time:

```
if(isset($_GET['column']) && isset($_GET['sense']))
{
    $sorting = (antiInjectie($_GET['sense']) == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    $temp = antiInjectie($_GET['column']);
    $order = (tableNameMatcher($temp)) ? $temp : '';
}
else
{
    $order = 'naam,voornaam';
    $sorting = 'ASC';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($sorting = "ASC"){ // here you store "ASC" into $sorting not comparing it
    $sorting = "DESC";
}else{
    $sorting = "ASC";
}
```

**NOW YOU HAVE TO DO THIS**

```
if($sorting == "ASC"){
    $sorting = "DESC";
}else{
    .
    .
.
```